# Permission denied errors on random files during branch checkout

Tags: git, git-extensions

All of a sudden, I started receiving the following error when checking out my local master branch. The problematic file, as well as the error itself, appears to be random (sometimes the checkout works perfectly fine).

> ```
> "c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" checkout --merge "master"
> D   abc123.cs
> error: unable to create file abc123.cs (Permission denied)
> Switched to branch 'master'
> Done
> ```

Comment: Most likely an anti-virus program is interferring here.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth As in, the anti-virus program is currently running a scan on those files? The problems been happening for 5 days now.

Comment: Yes, something like this. Try excluding that folder from the anti-virus program.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I couldn't make adjustments in the anti-virus program because it's controlled by IT administration. However, you're suggestion reminded me that I was running file recovery scans right before the errors started happening. I rebooted my machine in case any scan processes were left behind with a lock on those files. That appears to have fixed my issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it is resolved. Something like this is always annoying.

Comment: You should edit your question (and title) to show the issue has been resolved, so others don't need to read all of the comments to find out what the problem was.

Comment: @NevikRehnel I was going to add an answer once the waiting period was over, but I guess I could edit the question for now.

Comment: good call :) moving it to an answer later might be a good idea too, so it won't show up as "unanswered" anymore ;)

Comment: I have this issue all the time.  disabling antivirus doesn't fix it, killing searchprotocolhost and all file syncing programs doesn't fix it, killing explorer.exe doesn't fix it, etc. etc.  I just keep retrying until it randomly goes through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Daniel Hilgarth's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803039/permission-denied-errors-on-random-files-during-branch-checkout/61757476#comment18987538_13803039) anti-virus suggestion in the comments reminded me that I had run (and prematurely canceled) file recovery scans shortly before the problem manifested.

It's possible these scan processes were causing the problem if they didn't cancel properly.

Regardless, rebooting my machine fixed the issue.

Comment: i simply switched branches and back again, and it resolved the issue as well. rebooting is probably not necessary.

Answer (score 45):

Just closing the editor solved my issue. By the way, I was using Atom editor.

Comment: This helped me. I was using Atom and I had moved a folder from one parent folder to another. After checking out another branch, the folder was properly updated from git's perspective (to its old location since the move commit wasn't on that branch), but there was also a directory in the new location, empty, owned by me and with 755 rights but impossible to `rm -rf`. Any git maneuver would render a "cannot stat <folder>, permission denied". Neither `git reset --hard HEAD` nor `git clean -f` worked, but closing Atom made the directory accessible so I could `rm- rf` it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this fixes the problem, but makes you to close Atom everytime. so... how can this be fixed WITHOUT closing Atom? thanks!

Comment: It seems like the best approach would be for git to actually retry for a moment before giving up and letting the checkout get corrupted.  This happens to me all the time, so annoying.  In my case, definitely Sublime Text doing it.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if you're using sublime text, but when I got the permission denied problem, I noticed there was a license notice popup; that tries to get you to donate to sublimetext3 every once in a while.

Once I closed that popup and ran the commands again, the denied permission errors went away and everything worked fine.

I extrapolate that other editors with popup notices may cause this issue.

Rebooting, as bugged87 mentioned, would certainly get rid of any popups or notifications.

Comment: Looks like an open Sublime was causing my issue (even though the specific file wasn't open). Maybe it was running an index refresh or something.

Comment: Good observation. My sublime text is causing the problem. I just closed it and try to git status. then everything back to normal.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, my angular app was still running from `ng serve`, giving this:

[image: Git Bash - ng serve]

So I just had to close it with `ctrl+c`.

Answer (score 5):

The same happened with me a time ago and I've **closed my VScode**, typed `git checkout` and it worked!

Comment: Ran into the same issue with VSCode a minute ago. Windows 10. I closed VS code and then opened Git Bash and was able to checkout branches there.

Comment: Also, faced the same issue. It got resolved after closing the VScode but do you know what is the root cause of the problem ?

Comment: @AshwaniSharma In my case was the extension  vscode-gemfile, after uninstall it, works normally.

Answer (score 3):

Closing my text editor (Atom) fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution is to open Windows Task Manager and kill any IIS running instance.

Answer (score 2):

Close VSCode and run `git checkout master -f` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Closing all of my open sessions and starting a fresh one worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on Cmder console; I just closed it and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mistake in the OS level and does not relate to Git!

Sometimes the issue was resolved by closing the IDE and all the explorers, and sometimes it was solved by rebooting.

But the best solution is to create another folder and clone the project in it.
You can also delete old project after cloning. You would not see any permission denied issue in the new folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem on Win7.

For me the solution was to disable the **RealTime Protection** in **Microsoft Security Essentials** while doing the `git checkout master`

Just keep in mind to turn it back on again.

Comment: Can confirm that turning RealTime Protection off for a second fixed the issue. Turning it back on again didn't cause the issue again. Win10

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting is probably not necessary. You can try closing your editor or IDE and exiting from all your CMD or Windows shell,  currently set into that project folder.

Answer (score 0):

A heads up that the preview pane in Windows Explorer can also cause permissions errors.  I just spent an hour trying to hunt down what was causing the issue, thinking it was some kind of file corruption, when it suddenly became clear that as long as the preview pane was closed (or else that the file in question was not selected in the file explorer) then everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try closing VS Code Editor and Git Bash; then again opening Git Bash and running below command.

```
git checkout branch-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just closing the  Visual Studio Code editor solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mine solution is not pertinent to the Windows OS, since I had it on Linux, but for me it solved to change the ownership to the same user I had in other projects git repos. Eg my own account, I had there root for some probably mistake command I did.